# Wrap overloaded function via std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

I have an overloaded function which I want to pass along wrapped in a std::function. GCC4.6 does not find a "matching function".
While I did find some questions here the answers are not as clear as I would like them. Could someone tell me why the following code can not deduct the correct overload and how to (elegantly) work around it?

```
int test(const std::string&) {
    return 0;
}

int test(const std::string*) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::function<int(const std::string&)> func = test;
    return func();
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is ambiguous situation.

To disambiguate it, use explicit cast as:

```
typedef int (*funtype)(const std::string&);

std::function<int(const std::string&)> func=static_cast<funtype>(test);//cast!
```

Now the compiler would be able to disambiguate the situation, based on the type in the cast.

Or, you can do this:

```
typedef int (*funtype)(const std::string&);

funtype fun = test; //no cast required now!
std::function<int(const std::string&)> func = fun; //no cast!
```

So why `std::function<int(const std::string&)>` does not work the way `funtype fun = test` works above?

Well the answer is, because `std::function` can be initialized with any object, as its constructor is templatized which is independent of the template argument you passed to `std::function`.

Comment: Please use `static_cast` in place of old style cast.

Comment: @Anonymous: Yes. But I wanted to make it short. Anyway, I edited it to make it look like C++-ish!

Comment: How ironic - you have to use function pointers to get a std::function, which were introduced to get away from function pointers :) thx

Comment: @LCIDFire: `std::function` was not introduced to get rid of function pointers, but to provide a more general solution. You can use `std::function` and use any of function pointers, lambdas, functors (including binders)...