# Spawning thread from objects member function in main

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've been trying to work with threads and have an issue I cant seem to fix. I'm trying to spawn a thread from a member function that takes parameters however I have yet to be able to get it to not throw errors.

Heres what I have

```
ArraySorter s;
char *arr1, *arr2, *arr3;

arr1 = new char[MAXSIZE];
arr2 = new char[MAXSIZE];
arr3 = new char[MAXSIZE];

srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++)
{
    arr1[i] = arr2[i] = arr3[i] = rand() % MAXSIZE;
}

thread t1(&ArraySorter::InsertionSort, &s, arr1, MAXSIZE);
thread t2(&ArraySorter.MergeSort, arr2, MAXSIZE);
thread t3(&s.QuickSort, arr3, MAXSIZE);
```

To be clear all my sorting algorithms take a char * and integer in that order, All 3 ways of spawning the threads above do not work and I'm at a loss since I've tried the solutions I've found.

Declarations:

```
static void InsertionSort(int* arr, int n, int startIndex, int gap);
static void InsertionSort(int* arr, int n);
static void MergeSort(int* arr, int n);
static void QuickSort(int* arr, int n);
static void ShellSort(int* arr, int n, int* gapVals, int gapValsCount);
static void QuickSort(int *arr, int high, int low);
static int GetPivot(int *arr, int high, int low);
static void MergeArray(int *arr, int high, int mid, int low);
static void MergeSort(int *arr, int high, int low);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. The first one will compile if you remove the `&s` parameter. These are static members, no object is required. The rest will follow that same form. You shouldn't even need `s` declared.

Answer (score 0):

1. You create array of `char` and try to pass `char*`, but functions take `int*`. Either you need to change type somewhere, or make sorting functions templates.
2. You're not able to compile code because `thread` constructor could not deduce what function to use (for example `void InsertionSort(int* arr, int n, int startIndex, int gap)` or `void InsertionSort(int* arr, int n)`). One way to correct it is to rename functions. Another is to specify function pointer like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10111102/4182275).

   ```
   void(*insertion_1)(int*, int)      = &ArraySorter::InsertionSort;
   void(*insertion_2)(int*, int, int) = &ArraySorter::InsertionSort;
   ```

See full code of simplified example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

#define MAXSIZE 128

class ArraySorter {
public:
    static void InsertionSort(int* arr, int n) {
    }
    static void InsertionSort(int* arr, int n1, int n2) {
    }
};

int main() {
    int* arr1 = new int[MAXSIZE];
    int* arr2 = new int[MAXSIZE];
    int* arr3 = new int[MAXSIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++) {
        arr1[i] = arr2[i] = arr3[i] = rand() % MAXSIZE;
    }

    void(*insertion_1)(int*, int)      = &ArraySorter::InsertionSort;
    void(*insertion_2)(int*, int, int) = &ArraySorter::InsertionSort;
    thread t1(insertion_1, arr1, MAXSIZE);
    thread t2(insertion_2, arr1, MAXSIZE, 0);
    // Won't compile!
    // thread t3(&ArraySorter::InsertionSort, arr1, MAXSIZE);
}
```