# Does function pointers work while I am overloading the functions?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, overloading

I am just practicing function pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void print(){
    std::cout << "Printing VOID...\n";
}
void printI(int a){
    std::cout << "Printing INTEGER..."<<a<<"\n";
}
int main(){
    std::function<void(void)> p;
    std::function<void(int)> pi;
    p = print;
    pi = printI;
    p();
    pi(10);
}
```

Now this code works fine and gives me the output.. 
But what i want to do is to overload the print function like below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void print(){
    std::cout << "Printing VOID...\n";
}
void print(int a){
    std::cout << "Printing INTEGER..."<<a<<"\n";
}
int main(){
    std::function<void(void)> p;
    std::function<void(int)> pi;
    p = print;
    pi = print;
    p();
    pi(10);
}
```

But This code isn't working. It says unresolved address for print. Is there any way I can achieve both functionality? I mean Function pointer and Overloading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrap overloaded function via std::function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111042/wrap-overloaded-function-via-stdfunction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either try the standard `static_cast` method, or you could write a function template helper to do the type cohersion for you:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
auto assign_fn (std::function<Ret(Args...)> &f, Ret (*fp) (Args...))
{
    f = fp;
}
```

This is then used like so:

```
int main(){
    std::function<void(void)> p;
    std::function<void(int)> pi;
    assign_fn(p,print);
    assign_fn(pi,print);
    p();
    pi(10);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it working for convertible functions, e.g. call assign_fn on std::function<void(int)> and void(float)?